# How can i passing id which match?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS, please don't judge me.
So I fetch some user and I want to display them one by one, but as you can see in this picture I don't get the ID, but I get the id in the iteration

[image: items.id]

```
     import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import '../App.css';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    function Users() {
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchItems();
      }, []);

      const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

      const fetchItems = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        const items = await data.json();

        console.log(items.id);
        setItems(items);
      };
      return (
        <div>
          {items.map(item => (
            <h1 key={item.id}>
              <Link to={`/users/${item.id}`}>{item.name}</Link>
            </h1>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }

export default Users;
```

and here is my UserDetails :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

function UserDetail({ match }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
    console.log(match.id);
  }, [match]);

  const [user, userItem] = useState({});

  const fetchItem = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${match.id}`
    );
    const user = await data.json();
    console.log(user);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Item</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserDetail;
```

and i get this error.
I dont' get my id,and i don't know why.
[image: userdetails]

Comment: It should be `match.params.id` not `match.id`.

Comment: Yeah,that's the problem,thanks for the help!